# Some Script Error , not able to find solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I bounded data to dropdownlist but when i
click on button i want value of selected item but i cant get.and also its going refresh.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      async: false,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: "{}",
      url: "Drpodownlistbindingjquery.aspx/getdata",
      dataType: "json",
      success: ajaxSucceess,
      error: ajaxError
     });
     function ajaxSucceess(response){

      $.each(response.d, function (key, value) {
       $("#ddlCategory").append($("<option></option>").val(value.Sname).html(value.Sno));
      });

     }
     function ajaxError(response){
      alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);

     }       

    });
    </script>
```

And ,my second problem is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#btnsubmit").click(function(){     

       $.ajax({  

           type: "get",

           url: "loginform.aspx/getdataval",
           data:'{"uname":"'+$("#TextBox1").val()+'","passwod":"'+$("#TextBox2").val()+'"}',
           contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",   
           dataType: "json",         
           sucess:function(data){
           var Emp=data.d;
           alert('welcome');
           $("#output").append('<p>'+Emp.Sname+ ' ' + Emp.Sno+'</p>');
            //here i want to give redirect link
            },
            error: function(e) {
                 alert(e);
             }

   });
   });
   });
   </script>
```

i m comparing username and password but its giving error. anything is wrong here? 
**Drpodownlistbindingjquery.aspx is not a typo mistake** am sure.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sure this is a typo... `url: "Drpodownlistbindingjquery.aspx/getdata",`
should be dropdown, right?

Comment: Also in your getdataval method, if your parameters aren't exactly `string uname`, and `string passwod` it will fail. Was this also a typo? `data:'{"uname":"'+$("#TextBox1").val()+'","passwod":"'+$("#TextBox2").val()+'"}',` (passwod instead of password)

Comment: you also have typos in `sucess` and `Drpodownlistbindingjquery` and `ajaxSucceess`

Comment: in code behind parameters are like string uname, string passwod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second problem is easy:

```
sucess:function(data){
    var Emp=data.d;
```

`sucess` should be `success`.

And as [@nbrooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095384/some-script-error-not-able-to-find-solution/11095422#comment14529540_11095384) pointed out:

```
url: "Drpodownlistbindingjquery.aspx/getdata"
```

`Drpodown` *should* be `Dropdown`.

Comment: Dropdown is a url what value i give is drpodown so thats not a problem

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one:

```
data:{"uname":$("#TextBox1").val(),"password":$("#TextBox2").val()},
```